# How to reset index and find specific id?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have an `id` column for each person (data with the same id belongs to one person). I want these:

1. Now the `id` column is not based on numbering, it's 10 digit. How can I reset `id` with integers, e.g. *1, 2, 3, 4*?

For example:

```
id     col1
12a4   summer
12a4   goest
3b     yes
3b     No
3b     why
4t     Hi
```

Output:

```
id   col1
1    summer
1    goest
2    yes
2    No
2    why
3    Hi
```

2. How I can get the data corresponding to `id=2`?

In the above example:

```
id   col1
2    yes
2    No
2    why
```

Comment: any attempt made? try zipWithIndex, groupBy, ranking(dense??? forget), not that hard

Comment: is the ordering important?  you should state that.

Comment: no order is not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [
('12a4', 'summer'),
('12a4', 'goest'),
('3b', 'yes'),
('3b', 'No'),
('3b', 'why'),
('4t', 'Hi')
]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'col1'])
df1.show()
#     +----+------+
#     |  id|  col1|
#     +----+------+
#     |12a4|summer|
#     |12a4| goest|
#     |  3b|   yes|
#     |  3b|    No|
#     |  3b|   why|
#     |  4t|    Hi|
#     +----+------+

df = df1.select('id').distinct()
df = df.withColumn('new_id', F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('id')))
df.show()
#     +----+------+
#     |  id|new_id|
#     +----+------+
#     |12a4|     1|
#     |  3b|     2|
#     |  4t|     3|
#     +----+------+

df = df.join(df1, 'id', 'full')
df.show()
#     +----+------+------+
#     |  id|new_id|  col1|
#     +----+------+------+
#     |12a4|     1|summer|
#     |12a4|     1| goest|
#     |  4t|     3|    Hi|
#     |  3b|     2|   yes|
#     |  3b|     2|    No|
#     |  3b|     2|   why|
#     +----+------+------+

df = df.drop('id').withColumnRenamed('new_id', 'id')
df.show()
#     +---+------+
#     | id|  col1|
#     +---+------+
#     |  1|summer|
#     |  1| goest|
#     |  3|    Hi|
#     |  2|   yes|
#     |  2|    No|
#     |  2|   why|
#     +---+------+

df = df.filter(F.col('id') == 2)
df.show()
#     +---+----+
#     | id|col1|
#     +---+----+
#     |  2| yes|
#     |  2|  No|
#     |  2| why|
#     +---+----+
```